# Mui v5.0.4 makeStyles, withStyles won't apply styles to mui components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently working on a react (v.17) project which uses Mui v5.0.4. I've written custom styles where needed and everything was working as expected. After a couple of days I started working on the same project and when I launched the application that the styles I wrote did not appear as expected. This happened in specific components like Typography, Button. I've thoroughly checked my code, tried on different browsers and computers but no luck.

I created a new project to see if the problem is just limited to the previous one but that doesn't seem to be the case either. I will post the code snippets of the app below for reference.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import Something from './something/Something';

function App() {
  return <Something />;
}

export default App;
```

**Something.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { withStyles } from '@mui/styles';

import styles from './Something.styles';

const Something = ({ classes }) => {
  return <Typography className={classes.something}>Something</Typography>;
};

Something.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Something);
```

**Something.styles.js**

```
const styles = (theme) => ({
  something: {
    fontWeight: 700,
    color: '#FF0000'
  }
});

export default styles;
```

I should mention that the color does apply but the font-weight doesn't. `!important` gets the job done but I didn't need it before this issue came up. The applied style class does appear in the browser inspector, of which I have attached a screenshot of below.

[Click to check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMQHo.png)

I'm also curious as to why the classname is `.Something-something-1` and not `.Something-something`. Do ask for any additional information if needed. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

**P.S.** Here's a code sandbox to replicate the issue. Thanks!
https://codesandbox.io/s/long-sky-8jree

**Solution (for this specific problem)**

1. Use the following set of dependencies if you are using Mui v5.0.4

```
"@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
"@mui/material": "^5.0.4",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.3",
"@mui/styles": "^5.0.1",
```

2. Wrap the elements in `App.js` with a component from Mui (Box, Grid etc.).

```
import React from "react";
import { Box } from "@mui/material";

import Something from "./Something/Something";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Something />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I have updated the same code sandbox mentioned above with the working solution.

Comment: So the reason behind this issue was a conflict in the dependencies for Mui v5. It doesn't give you any errors but the styling won't apply unless the correct versions of the needed dependencies are available. I have added them for Mui v5.0.4 on the post itself in case anyone else needs it.

Comment: Wrapping the the elements in a parent Mui component (Box, Grid etc.) in `App.js` also seems to do the trick.

Comment: the second option worked for me, thanks a lot, was getting so irritated. However, I don't really understand why it fixes the issue, and wondering how did you find the solution as the docs are totally silent about that. Also, not sure why the first solution did no work for me as my project is brand new and I have the latest releases. Thanks

Comment: @Suren the dependencies are now listed in the docs. I don't think they were listed in the previous versions. As for the second solution, I figured this out by playing around with the code. Not sure if this was patched up in the newer versions. Glad I could help with your problem as well. :D

Answer (score 2):

**The easiest way to add style overrides for a one-off situation is to use the** `sx` **prop available on all MUI**. [reference](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/)

```js
import styles from './Something.styles';

const Something = ({ classes }) => {
  return <Typography sx={styles.something}>Something</Typography>;
 //classes prop wasn't needed here
};
```

[image]

Comment: In my case the issue was with the dependencies for Mui. I've updated the post with the solution that worked for me. The solution you provided doesn't seem to work in my case. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I had tested with the sandbox link provided. anyway glad you managed to solve it :)

Comment: Thanks @cmgchess. I've also figured out why your solution didn't work for me. I've exported the styles with the theme (`const styles = (theme) => ({})`). Yours worked when the styles were simply exported without the theme (`const styles = {}`). Regardless thanks to your answer now I know that the `sx` prop has another use. Thanks for sharing it with me. Happy coding. :D